# displaying image using codename one

Tags: json, symfony, codenameone

Hi im using codename one for a study project(mobile project) im resending data from symfony

I resended all the  attributes and they are displayed  except one which is the image is there any way for displaying the image to codenameone ?

Comment: When you say display it's unclear what you did as there are multiple ways to render data in Codename One and multiple ways to show images. If you want to show an image from a URL you might be interested in `URLImage`. If you want to show a downloaded image you can use `Image` or `EncodedImage`.  That image can be shown either via APIs such as `setIcon` on `Label` or APIs such as `ImageViewer`.

Comment: Is there any code involved you want to share?

Comment: im using vichuploader bundle for symfony and the image works on web but the problem is uploading the image to codenameone i couldnt figure out how it works to display the image from symfony to codenameone

Comment: the image's URL is allready saved in the database i want to read that and display it but since codenameone doesnt have a connection with the database it works from symfony that im using

Answer (score 0):

Since the Codenamone doesn't support direct connection to database , you can't directly get access the images so you will just have to download the pictures and save them to your projects  ,as for loading pictures i will assume you have a "path" variable in your entity
so u can use this :

```
Image img = null;
        try {
            img = Image.createImage("/"+ a.getPath()); 
        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }
```

a is the entity on load